# Large CSV file load into SQL Columnstore table Random Error , After restart same SSIS works fine

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, ssis-2012

I had experienced strange error while loading CSV file (, separated values) contain ~1.2 million rows into SQL (2016) columnstore table using SSIS package, I got following error rarely, especially on datetime columns.

After I simply restarted failed ETL it just works fine. We load same file in different environments and error appears only in one environment on same day.
I try to add error output and wait to see for next time, Meanwhile I would like to reach out to experts ask for help, if there is any issue with SQL columnstore table or SSIS while loading datatime values.

But error is while insert data, so it could be more of database side issue.

> PackageName > Sequence Container > DFL Transactions. SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. **Error code: 0x80004005.
> An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Invalid date format".**
> PackageName > Sequence Container > DFL Transactions. **There was an error with DST Transactions.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input].Columns[Account_FromDate] on DST Transactions.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]. The column status returned was: "Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the specified type."**.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the DFL Transactions sequence objects, and the code it uses?

Comment: Flat file loading into sql server is never straight forward, specially when you are dealing with comma separated files. I usually load data into SQL Server staging tables with a very loose data type something like varhcar(100), varhcar(200). Once I have the data in SQL Server then run some data validation checks and the rows that fail the check, insert those rows into a ErrorLog table and only process the rows that pass all your validation checks, now you have the power to get all fancy with you validation checks :)

Comment: When something works in one environment but not another it usually means configuration issues. Some things to check: check that the date values in your CSV files are all in the same format, i.e.: all dd/mm/yyyy, all mm/dd/yyyy, or all yyyy-mm-dd; check that the Windows Servers hosting your SQL Servers all have the same time zone and regional settings; since SQL Server language settings affect dateformat settings, and dateformat settings affect how it parses date-formatted strings, check that the default_language_name for all logins in master.sys.server_principals are set to the same thing.

Comment: @SchmitzIT, as you have asked added data flow image, it is simple and straight forward.

Comment: @M.Ali , Problem here is i can't able to re-produce error, as soon as start etl again it just works fine. And key issue here it was failing while inserting data into SQL table. Only option i have is add error output task permanently and wait for error next time.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning- This SSIS was running in production and uat for 5months now, there were no changes made to ssis or sql table. And both database servers are 2016 and same time zone and other configs as well except some hardware capacity differences. This ssis package failed on UAT in july (it went fine on prod same day), now it failed on production (went fine on uat). we load exact same file in both uat and prod env.